# pybind11: how to convert a C++ function that return pointer?

Tags: python, c++, pointers, function-pointers, pybind11

How to convert a C++ function that return pointer? Just like:

```
int * getRandom( )
{
  static int  r[10];
 
  srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    r[i] = rand();
    cout << r[i] << endl;
  }
 
  return r;
}
```

How should I bind to convert this C++ function to python?

```
m.def("getRandom", &getRandom, py::return_value_policy::reference);
```

The above method can only return the first number of the array. In python side, How should I do to get the array value with length of 10 that function `getRandom` generate in C++ code.

Comment: How is python supposed to know that the int pointer is actually part of an array owned on the C++ side? You need to return something that pybind can interpret as either list or directly numpy array.

Comment: How should I do to return list or numpy array? May you give an example or more detailed explanation? I am not familiar with pybind11 now.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```cpp
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

// ...

pybind11::array_t<int> getRandomWrapper(void)
{
    int* values = getRandom();

    pybind11::capsule cleanup(values, [](void *f) {});

    return pybind11::array_t<int>(
       {10},          // shape
       {sizeof(int)}, // stride
       values,   // pointer to data
       cleanup        // garbage collection callback
    );
}
```

and then just

```cpp
m.def("getRandom", &getRandomWrapper);
```

(`return_value_policy::reference` is not appropriate here as you are not directly referencing `r`.)

The fourth argument to the `array_t<int>` constructor is a wrapper or "capsule" around a function that describes how to free the array's underlying memory. In this case you are returning a pointer to something managed by "automatic storage" so there is nothing to cleanup, hence it does nothing.

If, on the other hand, you were dynamically allocating the returned array you would need something like

```cpp
pybind11::capsule cleanup(values, [](void *f) {
    delete[] static_cast<int*>(values);
});
```